# Your xorg.conf does not contain any XkbLayoout options Error in puppyLinux

Tags: keyboard-layout, xorg.conf, puppylinux

I don't know what I did wrong, was it a wrong package or something else. Now I can't change the keyboard layout. Is there a way to reset the setting of xkb to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in puppylinux forums.
An script should be run after installing a pet package.
the source of the script:
http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=118115